# trying to create a php foreach loop which generates a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

So I have this script which im trying to create a filelist.js file from in php here's the code:

```
//CREATE fileslist.js
$thumbssize = "1";
$moviesize= "1";
$thumbarray = array_slice(scandir($tpath), 2);

echo print_r($thumbarray) . "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $script="
fileList = {};
fileList[\"thumbs\"] = {};
fileList[\"movies\"] = {};
fileList[\"title\"]=\"{$foldername}\";";

foreach($thumbarray as $item) {
print "fileList[\"thumbs\"][1]=["$item['0']","$item['2']","$item['3']","$item['4']","$item['5']","$item['6']"];";
    }

$script2 = "    
fileList[\"thumbs\"][\"size\"]={$thumbssize};
fileList[\"thumbs\"][\"size\"]={$moviesize};";

//$script = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $script);
$scriptName= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/{$foldername}/assets/js/filelist.js";
file_put_contents($scriptName, trim($script . $script2) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
echo "Generating filelist.js</br>";
    }
```

This here is the example output of the array:

```
Array ( [0] => 863_example_r003.mp4 [1] => 863_example_r004.mp4 [2] => 863_example_r005.mp4 [3] => 863_example_r006.mp4 [4] => 863_example_r007.mp4 ) 1
```

This is the filelist.js output as it stands right now:

```
fileList = {};
fileList["thumbs"] = {};
fileList["movies"] = {};
fileList["title"]="test7";

fileList["thumbs"]["size"]=1;

fileList["thumbs"]["size"]=1;
```

So up until this point its doing what i want except I cannot figure out how to make a foreach loop to generate this type of output :

```
fileList = {};
fileList["thumbs"] = {};
fileList["movies"] = {};
fileList["title"]="863-example";
fileList["thumbs"][1]=["863_example_r048.mp4","863_example_r049.mp4","863_example_r050.mp4","863_example_r051.mp4","863_example_r052.mp4","863_example_r053.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][2]=["863_example_r054.mp4","863_example_r055.mp4","863_example_r056.mp4","863_example_r057.mp4","863_example_r058.mp4","863_example_r059.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][3]=["863_example_r060.mp4","863_example_r061.mp4","863_example_r062.mp4","863_example_r003.mp4","863_example_r063.mp4","863_example_r064.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][4]=["863_example_r065.mp4","863_example_r004.mp4","863_example_r067.mp4","863_example_r068.mp4","863_example_r069.mp4","863_example_r070.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][5]=["863_example_r005.mp4","863_example_r071.mp4","863_example_r072.mp4","863_example_r073.mp4","863_example_r074.mp4","863_example_r006.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][6]=["863_example_r075.mp4","863_example_r076.mp4","863_example_r077.mp4","863_example_r078.mp4","863_example_r007.mp4","863_example_r079.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][7]=["863_example_r080.mp4","863_example_r081.mp4","863_example_r082.mp4","863_example_r008.mp4","863_example_r083.mp4","863_example_r084.mp4"];
fileList["thumbs"][8]=["863_example_r085.mp4","863_example_r086.mp4","863_example_r009.mp4","863_example_r087.mp4","863_example_r088.mp4","863_example_r089.mp4"];
```

The [1], [2], [3] refers to a page number and there needs to be 6 items per page as the example above

Comment: what's wrong with using json_encode?

Comment: Did you have an actual question? Or are you just asking us to fix it for you?

Comment: The question is how would i go about getting what i need to accomplish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. Just a minute ago I refined the code and tested it in my localhost. Here is the changed code that gives the result:

```
$script1 = "";
$i       = 0;
$j       = 0;
$inrow   = 6; // files in row
foreach($thumbarray as $item => $itemv) {

  // beginning of the row
  if($j % $inrow == 0){ 
    $script1 .= "\nfileList[\"thumbs\"][".($i+1)."]=[";
  }

  $script1 .= "\"" . $itemv . "\","; // add filename "863_example_r048.mp4",

  // end of the row
  if(($j + $inrow + 1) % $inrow == 0){
    // Delete comma at end of row
    if(substr($script1,-1) == ","){ 
      $script1 = substr($script1, 0, strlen($script1) - 1);
    }
    $script1 .= "];";
  }
  if($j % $inrow == 0){ 
    $i++;
  }
  $j++;
}
```

Here is the tested result:

`fileList["thumbs"][1]=[".AndroidStudio1.3",".ICEauthority",".PlayOnLinux",".Skype",".Xauthority",".adobe"];
fileList["thumbs"][2]=[".android",".audacity-data",".bash_history",".bashrc",".bibletime",".cache"];
fileList["thumbs"][3]=[".claws-mail",".config",".dbus",".directory",".dmrc",".dosbox"];
fileList["thumbs"][4]=[".emacs",".esd_auth",".fltk",".fontconfig",".fonts",".fonts.conf"];
fileList["thumbs"][5]=[".frozen-bubble",".gimp-2.8",".gnome",".gnome2",".gnome2_private",".gnupg"];
fileList["thumbs"][6]=[".gstreamer-0.10",".gtkrc-2.0",".gvfs",".icewm",".inputrc",".ivy2"];
fileList["thumbs"][7]=[".java",".jsword",".kde",".kde4",".kismet",".local"];
fileList["thumbs"][8]=[".macromedia",".mozilla",".mplayer",".mtpaint",".opera",".pki"];
fileList["thumbs"][9]=[".profile",".putty",".pyhistory",".qt",".remmina",".sbt"];
fileList["thumbs"][10]=[".skel",".ssh",".streamtuner",".sword",".themes",".thumbnails"];
fileList["thumbs"][11]=[".thunderbird",".vnc",".wine",".xboardrc",".xdg_menu_cache",".xim.template"];
fileList["thumbs"][12]=[".xinitrc.template",".xiphos",".xscreensaver",".xsession-errors",".xsession-errors-192.168.1.101:1",".xsession-errors-192.168.1.103:1"];
fileList["thumbs"][13]=[".xsession-errors-:0",".xsession-errors-:1",".y2log",".y2usersettings","20150901_134031.jpg","281436_wpmu-dev-dashboard-3.5.3.zip"];
fileList["thumbs"][14]=["Android","AndroidStudioProjects","Bible Analyzer User Modules","Calibre Library","Desktop","Documents"];
fileList["thumbs"][15]=["Downloads","Java","Kismet-20141124-23-54-29-1.alert","Kismet-20141124-23-54-29-1.gpsxml","Kismet-20141124-23-54-29-1.nettxt","Kismet-20141124-23-54-29-1.netxml"];
fileList["thumbs"][16]=["Kismet-20141124-23-54-29-1.pcapdump","Movies","Music","Phpgtk","Pictures","PlayOnLinux's virtual drives"];
fileList["thumbs"][17]=["Public","Templates","Videos","VirtualBox VMs","WPMUDEV_PLUGINS.zip","battery"];
fileList["thumbs"][18]=["bibleanalyzer","bibledesktop-2.0-beta","bin","ca.key","deklaracia.jpg","deklaracia2.jpg"];
fileList["thumbs"][19]=["dfc","http:⁄⁄www.biblestudytools.com⁄niv⁄.desktop","konq","projects","public_html","scala"];
fileList["thumbs"][20]=["somefile","somefile.txt","viber","wget-log","wp-cron.php?import_key=d&import_id=20&action=processing","Запис0003.amr"];`

Comment: Yeah i made them same changes except i couldnt get the first two rows to close correctly with the ]; all is working now exceptionally

Answer (score 0):

you need to change below part

```
$index = 1;
foreach($thumbarray as $item) {
 $script .= "fileList[\"thumbs\"][$index]= ".json_encode($item).";" ;
 $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two indexes. $i is incremented every time $i is deleted in $inrow times properly with the remainder of 0. If you want 6 rows of files then $i should be increased 6 times less then $j which is increased every time. This way $i would change when $j is 6,12,18,24 and etc. You will need to play a little bit with the code ...

```
$script1 = "";
$i       = 0;
$j       = 0
$inrow   = 6; // files in row
foreach($thumbarray as $item => $itemv) {

  // beginning of the row
  if($j % $inrow == 0){ 
    $script1 .= "fileList[\"thumbs\"][".($i+1)."]=[";
  }

  $script1 .= "\"" . $itemv . "\","; // add filename "863_example_r048.mp4",

  // end of the row
  if($j % $inrow == 0){
    // Delete comma at end of row
    if(substr($script1,-1) == ","){ 
      $script1 = substr($script1, 0, strlen($script1) - 1);
    }
    $script1 .= "]";
    $i++;
  }
  $j++;
}
```

Comment: At first I wrote a code with one index but this wouldn't work because there can be thousands of files in the directory! The $i index must increment not on every foreach iteration but after the maximum number of files in a row is reached.

Comment: willt try this shortly and report back

Comment: the output of the JS added below

Comment: fileList["thumbs"][".(0+1)."]=["863_example_r003.mp4"]"863_example_r004.mp4","863_example_r005.mp4","863_example_r006.mp4","863_example_r007.mp4","863_example_r008.mp4",fileList["thumbs"][".(1+1)."]=["863_example_r009.mp4"]"863_example_r010.mp4","863_example_r011.mp4","863_example_r012.mp4","863_example_r013.mp4","863_example_r014.mp4",fileList["thumbs"][".(2+1)."]=["863_example_r015.mp4"]"863_example_r016.mp4","863_example_r017.mp4","863_example_r018.mp4","863_example_r019.mp4","863_example_r020.mp4",

Comment: almost there thanks alot im sure i can figure it out from here ill get back to you on the acceptance of it

Comment: I have tried such code on one of the sites I develop but not to create JS files.